# Converting string into valid json with Python

Tags: python, json, validation

This string is returned to my app:

```
[
  {
    "object1": "here",
    "morekeys": "can also have objects as values"
  }
  {
    "object2": "here",
    "morekeys": "can also have objects as values"
  }
]
```

The string is not valid JSON. All that's missing is the comma between the two valid JSON objects.

What's the best method to turn this string into valid JSON with Python?

Edit:

The string is the result of calling subprocess.check_output(), like for example this:

```
my_string = "[" + subprocess.check_output("command1 && command2", shell=True, stderr=STDOUT) + "]"
```

Since each command outputs a valid JSON object, I am receiving invalid JSON as a result.

Comment: Are there more examples? What happens when there are more than two elements? Is this the case for all lists or only top-level lists.

Comment: The string is received with subprocess.check_output(). The string is the result of concatenating multiple commands with '&&' (and wrapping the result with [ ]).  Since each tool produces its own valid JSON output, I am receiving this invalid concatenated json. There could be more than two elements (in which case there would be several commas missing in between the valid json objects).

Comment: That's.... so wrong. At the very least then add commas in that shell command, stripping the last comma is *far easier*.

Comment: But each command can be executed on its own. If I add a trailing comma, then the individual tools would produce invalid JSON.

Comment: I didn't say the commands themselves should add the trailing comma, I said the shell command you used to concatenate their output should.

Comment: Consider `json-line` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject commas in your shell command instead:

```
my_string = "[{}]".format(
    subprocess.check_output("command1 && echo ',' && command2",
                            shell=True, stderr=STDOUT, env=env))
```

Answer (score 1):

RegExp?

```
import re
re.sub(r'}(\s*){', r'},\1{', my_string)
```